# Select max int from varchar column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve the largest number from a varchar column that includes both numbers and strings. An example of the data I'm working with:

**BoxNumber**
123
A5
789
B1

I need to return the largest number (789 in this case) from the column while ignoring the non-numeric values of A5 and B1.

I have found solutions that use [custom functions](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6423) to solve the problem, but I need something that can be executed ad-hoc query without relying on custom functions or procs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you need a combination because of the fact that isnumeric returns 1 for the following things

```
select isnumeric('+'),isnumeric('5d2')
```

your where clause would be like this

```
WHERE VALUE NOT LIKE '%[a-z]%'
        AND ISNUMERIC(VALUE) = 1

create table #bla (value varchar(50))
insert #bla values('123')
insert #bla values('a5')
insert #bla values('789')
insert #bla values('b1')

SELECT MAX(CAST(value AS Int)) FROM #bla
WHERE VALUE NOT LIKE '%[a-z]%'
    AND ISNUMERIC(VALUE) = 1
```

I wrote about this here [ISNUMERIC Trouble](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/ISNUMERIC_Trouble)

Answer (score 9):

You might try

```
Select MAX(BoxNumber) from {table} where IsNumeric(BoxNumber) = 1
```

Comment: If this query will be used regularly make sure you evaluate its performance.

Comment: Isnumeric can not be used, run this to see what I mean  
select isnumeric('+'),isnumeric('5d2')

Answer (score 7):

Why not

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(Value AS Int)) FROM #bla 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(Value)=1 
    AND Value LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

then you're only dealing with numeric strings.  In this case you may not need ISNUMERIC()

Answer (score 4):

The selected answer worked for me until I added this value to the temp table along with the others in the sample:

```
insert #bla values('1234')
```

I expected my max() result to now be 1234, but it remained at 789. Perhaps this is due to some collation setting, but I was able to reproduce on multiple databases. I found this query below worked for me, but I'd certainly be interested to hear if there is a more efficient way of doing this. Also, I did not want to include any decimal values, so I excluded anything with a period as well.

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(Value AS Int)) FROM #bla 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(Value)=1 
    AND Value NOT LIKE '%[a-z]%' 
    AND Value NOT LIKE '%.%'
```

Comment: I want to use this for multiple max values which are all values from different columns. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should check this solution out for values like '+' and '-' as I think the IsNumeric function may return 1 for these values

Answer (score 2):

Well, in the intervening 11 years since this question was asked, SQL Server gained the [`try_cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function, which returns `null` rather than throwing an error if the conversion doesn't succeed.  So in current versions of SQL Server, a valid answer is

```sql
select max(try_cast(BoxNumber as int)) from theTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into casting the column to an int, then selecting the MAX().  I don't know what it will do to columns that contain letters, but it's worth exploring.

http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/ca-co_1.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It errors out unfortunately: Syntax error converting the nvarchar value 'A5' to a column of data type int.

Answer (score 1):

These answers are only half right.  They succeed in isolating numeric values, but don't realize that when the underlying field is a number the Max function evaluates as characters (regardless of casting), reading left to right, so that 789 > 1000 because 7 > 1.  A way around this might be to forget about casting and left pad the numbers with zeros to a common length, when Max in character mode should work.

Comment: It looks like solutions like SQLMenace's that cast to an int work correctly. Is there a specific version of SQL Server where you found that this approach doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(value as signed)) FROM yourTable
WHERE VALUE NOT LIKE '%[a-z]%'
AND ISNUMERIC(VALUE) = 1
```

In MySql

You should use signed instead of int to cast correctly.

P.s types used to cast may differ in MySql

For more conversions visit [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp) link

Comment: The question is for SQL Server / T-SQL, not MySQL.  SQL Server does not have a "signed" data type.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(cast(column as numeric)) from table
```

Where column was varchar which was casted to numeric in postgresql